How do I create an easy way to unclog main sewer line?
I've had my main sewer line clog in the same area 3 times since I've bought the place in 2021. Here is a quick diagram of the afflicted area:

A: Is the main sewer cleanout facing the city sewer. In all three incidents, there were no discernable clog in that direction when I tested with a 20ft snake.
B: This is always the location of where the clog is located. I don't know exactly where it is, but it is between clean out A and C.
C: This is the main cleanout I use to scrape the line to clear the clog. There is usually tens of gallons of sewer water when a clog is detected. So the main idea here is to quickly get rid of the water such that I can attack the clog.

C1: I utilize the existing cleanout tee and install a reducer from 4 in to 2 in and a 2 in valve with a garden hose adapter. The idea here is to either use gravity or a pump to pump out the sewage water above cleanout C. (waiting for the water to drain often takes the most time).
C2: I cut and install a 4 in valve above cleanout C. When there is a clog, I close the valve and would only need to drain 1-2 gallons of water before the cleanout is clear.
D: If the proposals for C1 and C2 are NOGO, then the alternative is to install a house-facing cleanout such that I can attack the clog from the outside instead of needing to drain the lines above cleanout C before I can begin. This would take the most time as far as I am aware, and it would allow me to replace any collapsed section if there was any.
Question 1:
What is the best way for me to unclog the main line if this keeps happening? Note that I would be DIY any solution here, so time is not necessarily the factor. Cost would be significant if I hired contractors.
Question 2:
Not related to the clog, but whenever I open the cleanout C and let the wastewater pool directly in the area below it, it seems to drain pretty quickly into the ground. What would explain this? Would this indicate a collapsed drain somewhere in B where the water is going, or is the ground (mainly clay) absorbing the wastewater that quickly?

I would wonder why you are having the clogs at all. Might be worth having a pro deal with it once to clear it out completely, and reconsider what you are putting down the drain

An inspection camera might reveal the source of the clogs and suggests a more permanent fix. Some plumbers will inspect for free, others will charge a visit or more. You can also rent a plumbing camera from tool rental places like Home Depot.

One thing you should certainly do if you dig up the exterior cleanouts: swap locations of Cleanout-A and Cleanout-D. The normal configuration is opposite of your drawing, so as to eliminate a "dead spot" that can't be cleaned between A and D.

@keshlam standard house waste, grey water, human fecal and urine waste. No paper towel, wet wipe, etc...

@EliIser noted, good idea. Now I am wondering if I should just buy one instead, any recommendations?

@JimmyFix-it good idea, I'll be sure to swap them if I go down that route.

Are the drain pipes cast iron or plastic (PVC or ABS)? Is the foundation pier and beam or slab?

@JimStewart foundation is concrete blocks. This is a split level home. All sewage plumbing is PVC.

Definitely get a plumber to look at the drains with a camera before you think about digging up the line.
It appears that the cleanout C allows access to the drain between A and B. You do not have an inaccessible section. Other things being equal it appears it would be better for the directionality of the cleanouts A and B to be reversed (that is the way my house is done) but there may be a reason for the way yours is done.

The trouble with cleanout C is that it is generally below the water line when the line gets clogged. There is about 20-30 gallons of water in the main line to the kitchen sink (the lowest point in system). So the main pain point here is draining the line to where I can get at the clog.

I repeat--get a camera into the line and see what the situation is. It is not that expensive, at least where I live in Dallas. Do you have trees nearby? I love baldcypress trees but they can send roots a long way and if there is a poorly glued joint in PVC plumbing, they will find it.

Confirmed - will get a camera.

2: B. Ground generally absorbs water pretty fast. To prove it to yourself, pour a similar quantity of water on the ground elsewhere.

thanks! I thought the worst and thought everything was draining so quickly due to a collapsed sewer line.

Pour down baking soda followed by vinegar, preferably white spirit vinegar.

And exactly what does that do?

pour where? ...
